# Querying wikidata for "property constraint"

Tags: sparql, wikidata

TL;DR
How to query (sparql) about properties of a property?

Or..
So as part of my project I need to find the properties in wikidata that have any time constraint, to be specific both "start time" and "end time".
I tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?prop WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?person ?prop ?statement.
  ?statement pq:P580 ?starttime.
  ?statement pq:P582 ?endtime.
}
LIMIT 200
```

**yeah the properties should be related to humans
Anyway, I do get some good results like:
http://www.wikidata.org/prop/P26
http://www.wikidata.org/prop/P39
But I also get some other properties that definitely wrong.

so, basically what i'm trying to do is to get a list of properties that has the property constraint (P2302) of- allowed qualifiers constraint (Q21510851) with Start time (P580) and End Time (P582)
is that even possible:
I tried some queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyDescription ?subpTypeOf ?subpTypeOfLabel 
WHERE
{
    ?property rdf:type wikibase:Property .

    ?property wdt:P2302  ?subpTypeOf.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }   
}
```

but does not get the results I wanted.
is it even possible to query this kind of stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers) are used on property pages too. Your second query should be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?prop ?propLabel {
  ?prop p:P2302 [ ps:P2302 wd:Q21510851 ; pq:P2306 wd:P580, wd:P582 ] ;
        p:P2302 [ ps:P2302 wd:Q21503250 ; pq:P2308 wd:Q5 ; pq:P2309 wd:Q21503252 ] .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
} ORDER BY ASC(xsd:integer(strafter(str(?prop), concat(str(wd:), "P"))))
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fprop%20%3FpropLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fprop%20p%3AP2302%20%5B%20ps%3AP2302%20wd%3AQ21510851%20%3B%20pq%3AP2306%20wd%3AP580%2C%20wd%3AP582%20%5D%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%3AP2302%20%5B%20ps%3AP2302%20wd%3AQ21503250%20%3B%20pq%3AP2308%20wd%3AQ5%20%3B%20pq%3AP2309%20wd%3AQ21503252%20%5D%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28xsd%3Ainteger%28strafter%28str%28%3Fprop%29%2C%20concat%28str%28wd%3A%29%2C%20%22P%22%29%29%29%29)

Your first query is correct, but note that this is an 'as-is' query. For example, [wd:P410](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P410) does not have respective constraints, but look at [wd:Q83855](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q83855#P410).

Comment: Great, thank you so much!
Can you explain more about the differences between p:P2302 , ps:P2302, and when should I use each prefix.

Comment: @OmriMyers, these prefixes are described here: https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Data_model.